# What does "mkdir /mnt 0700 shell shell" do in init.rc..?

Tags: android, mkdir

I am trying to understand android init.rc file. in the file i could see a line "mkdir /mnt 0700 shell shell". What does this line does..? will it create the folders named mnt, 0700, shell..?

when i ran this command in linux PC, its creating three directories name mnt, 0700, shell and giving an error to create one more shell director since its already created a folder named shell. I wanted to know what does this command does in int.rc file.

Thanks in advance..

Regards,

Comment: What is the `android` tag doing in here?

Comment: As you noticed right, a normal `mkdir` would create the 4 given directories. This will fail as `shell` is given twice. This indicates that `mkdir` is implemented differently in Android. `0700` is a typical file permission so I'm assuming it's that. If there is a permission the rest might be the owner (user and group). So I'd say it creates the folder `/mnt` with the owner `shell:shell` and the permission `0700`. But as I said: Just guessing...

Comment: @devnull Android tag here because its regarding Android Initial Script question.

Answer (score 3):

The commands in the init.rc file are special language used by the android init process.

The syntax is loosely described in a readme file in the AOSP source code:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md

by in particular the command you are asking about will create a directory called "/mnt" with the unix permissions "0700" owned by the user "shell" and the group "shell".

I hope that helps.